# Delete a single row in Parse using Swift 3

Tags: parse-platform, swift3, xcode8

I need some help! I can't seem to delete just a single row from Parse. I have the "Swipe to delete" figured out, however, when you try and delete something form the table, it doesn't do anything. I get no errors. Nothing gets deleted. This is my code.

```
      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // delete from server
        let myFeatherquery = PFQuery(className: "FeatherPosts")

        myFeatherquery.whereKey("message", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)
        myFeatherquery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("THERE WAS AN ERROR")
            }else{
                for object in objects!{
                    self.messages.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    object.deleteInBackground()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In short, I want to delete a post from the `tableView` and delete it on the parse side as well. If I change:

`"myFeatherquery.whereKey("message", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)"`

**to**

```
"myFeatherquery.whereKey("userid", equalTo: (PFUser.current()?.objectId!)!)"
```

it just deleted everything that the user has ever posted. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to query inside `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` becasue `IndexPath` is already established which one you want to delete.

Now I've added a few extra bit to this logic.

1:) You can slide the cell to view the delete button. Once clicked it will confirm if you want to delete.
2:) Once deleted a fade will take place. It will then refresh the `tableView` and delete the object in parse in the background.

`FeatherPostsArray` that you see I made is your array of objects you used in the `tableView`. In your `numberOfRowsInSection` you would have done a count on it.

So this is what it should be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        var recClass = PFObject(className:"FeatherPosts")
        recClass = self.FeatherPostsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]



        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "App Name",
                                          message: "You sure you want to delete?",
                                          preferredStyle: .alert)

            let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

                recClass.deleteInBackground {(success, error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {

                    }}

                self.FeatherPostsArray.remove(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                tableView.reloadData()
            })
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in })
            alert.addAction(delete)
            alert.addAction(cancel)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        //This is nice if you want to add a edit button later
        return [ deleteAction]

    }
```

Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: This worked. I had to tweak it a little, but it worked great! Thanks!